# Is there a way to force the user to select values from two different filters and visualization data changes accordingly?

Tags: visualization, ironpython, spotfire

I have two listbox filters Filter 1 : Employee Filter 2: Project , There is a cross tab visualization of the data. Now i dont want cross tab visualization data to be changed when user selects only the name, only when user selects employee name and a project only then the data in the cross tab visualization should change. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Will the filters always be selected in that order?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two filters create a hierarchy filter or a calculated column with Employee + Project so that the user is interacting with only one visual.

Other option would be to create document properties for both *filters* and using python scripts attached to the document property to update the filters only when both document properties have values. This is a lot of coding though since you'll have to pass document properties values to a filter.